# How to handle large file stream in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, .net-core-3.1, coreclr

I have the following code to download files from S3 and then zip it. For brevity i have excluded some of the code.

```
  public Download(IList<string> urls)
  {
    var maxConcurrentDownloads = 20;
    var sourceStreams = new List<Stream>(); 
    var zipStream = new VirtualStream();        
    try
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++)
        {
            var url = urls[i];
            var stream = new VirtualStream();                    
            AmazonS3Uri s3Uri = null;
            if (AmazonS3Uri.TryParseAmazonS3Uri(url, out s3Uri))
            {
                //GetObject downloads the file from S3 using `AmazonS3Client`
                // For brevity GetObject code is not included.
                tasks.Add(GetObject(s3Uri, stream));
            }

            if (tasks.Count == maxConcurrentDownloads || i == urls.Count - 1)
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                tasks.Clear();
            }
        }

        
        using (System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            for(int i =0;i<sourceStreams.Count;i++)
            {
                
                var zipItem = zip.CreateEntry("file"+i.ToString()+".pdf");
  
                using (var entryStream = zipItem.Open())
                {
                    var source  = sourceStreams[i];
                    await source.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
                }
            }
        }

         //upload zip file to S3. For brevity Upload code is not included.
        _s3Client.Upload(zipStream);      
    }
    finally
    {
        zipStream.Dispose();
        foreach(var s in sourceStreams)
        {
           s.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works fine on Windows Server.
The `VirtualStream` is a special class. Internally it uses `MemoryStream` and when the stream size goes beyond 4MB it creates persistent stream (Physicals file) temp directory. Here is the [code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/14192551/)

For large number of files it consumes server resources that affect other app functionalities. I want to move download functionality to AWS Lambda using .NET Core 3.1.

However I have questions
1>Looks like creating persistent stream will only works on Windows Machine. In serverless environments, which might not be windows, if the file size goes beyond 4MB where will virtual stream create persistent stream?
2> I can change the code and always use `MemoryStream`, however the final zipfile could be in GBs. Is it recommended?
3>Is there any other recommended Stream for large file handling in serverless enviroment?

*Quick google search shows aws examples but they are mostly using NodeJs*

Comment: You're streaming files in from S3, zipping the stream, and streaming the output to a ZIP file in S3? Doesn't seem unreasonable. Lambda has a small amount of /tmp disk space (500MB). I'd be sure to configure the Lambda function with a large amount of RAM (e.g. 3008 GB).

Comment: Individual files are small, but zip file size keep increasing as we add new files and I believe that operation will be done in memory.  Should I always use `MemoryStream` then?

Comment: This might help: https://www.antstack.io/blog/create-zip-using-lambda-with-files-streamed-from-s3/

Comment: I saw that earlier but its its in nodejs. There are lot of examples using nodejs but couldn't' t find anything using C#.NEt Core

Comment: I don't know anything about .Net streaming capabilities here, but if it's a standalone Lambda and you can't identify a .Net solution, then it might be worth switching to Node for this one specific situation.